# Mathplot lib error on Python

Tags: python, libraries, python3

I am trying to run a code on `python` which needs `mathplotlib`. By typing:

```
python3 mouse_click.py
```

gives the error

```
ImportError: No module named 'matplotlib'
```

For installing

```
sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib
```

Result is:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python-matplotlib is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libtcl8.5 libtk8.5 tcl8.5 tk8.5
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

It shows that everything is ok and I already installed it. But it is not.

After that i have tried:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-mathplotlib
```

Result:

```
E: Unable to locate package python3-mathplotlib
```

Then I have tried:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep python-matplotlib
```

Here is the the result of above code:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Picking 'matplotlib' as source package instead of 'python-matplotlib'
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3-all-dbg : Depends: libpython3-all-dbg (= 3.4.0-0ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: python3-dbg (= 3.4.0-0ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: python3.4-dbg but it is not going to be installed
 python3-all-dev : Depends: libpython3-all-dev (= 3.4.0-0ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: python3-dev (= 3.4.0-0ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: python3.4-dev but it is not going to be installed
 python3-numpy-dbg : Depends: python3-dbg but it is not going to be installed
E: Build-dependencies for python-matplotlib could not be satisfied.
```

Finally:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep python3-matplotlib
```

Result:

```
Picking 'matplotlib' as source package instead of 'python3-matplotlib'
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3-all-dbg : Depends: libpython3-all-dbg (= 3.4.0-0ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: python3-dbg (= 3.4.0-0ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: python3.4-dbg but it is not going to be installed
 python3-all-dev : Depends: libpython3-all-dev (= 3.4.0-0ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: python3-dev (= 3.4.0-0ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: python3.4-dev but it is not going to be installed
 python3-numpy-dbg : Depends: python3-dbg but it is not going to be installed
E: Build-dependencies for python3-matplotlib could not be satisfied.
```

I did not installed any python, because `ubuntu 14.04` already have `Python 3.4.3`. I need help about installing `mathplotlib` to run my code.

Comment: python3 needs `python3-matplotlib` surely?

Comment: i did not understand your question

Comment: I meant that your apt-get output only shows that the python2 version (python-matplotlib) is installed, whereas you appear to be running your code using python3

Comment: @isifzade, try with `sudo apt-get install python3-matplotlib`

Comment: Thanks you for reply,  I have updated my post.  Please look at the results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use `python3` and therefore you need `python3-matplotlib` but you have made one mistake:

The name of the package is `python3-matplotlib` and **not** `python3-mathplotlib`.

Therefore install

```
sudo apt-get install python3-matplotlib
```

---

Installing the development libraries via

```
sudo apt-get build-dep …
```

isn't necessary.